# Remove Trailing slash from Wordpress slug

Tags: wordpress, slug, trailing-slash

I want to retrieve the slug of the current page in Wordpress.
This works:

```
<?php global $post; $post_slug=$post->post_name;?>
```

But it contains a trailing slash. I want to trim the traling slash, how can I do that?
Thanks?

Comment: did you try **anything** to solve the problem on your own, or have you been too lazy?

Comment: yes I did try to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

$post_slug = rtrim($post->post_name,"/");

Comment: Hi Thanks, but very strange, I still get the trailing slash with your solution, I solved it like this now : 
<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>